# Incomplete form still submitting in PHP

Tags: php, jquery, validation

When I fill the form one or two field in the form and click on register button,  its still submitting those values. It should not submit till the all field complete in the form. What am I doing wrong???

I have added a `<pre />` tag at the top so that I can check which values are entered, here is my code:

Start of file - PHP:

```
<?php

$error_array = array();
$fname = $lname = $email = $dob = $Mchecked = $gender = $Fchecked = $hobbies ="";

if(isset($_POST["sbt_save"]))
{   
echo '<pre>'; print_r($_POST); echo "</pre>";
    if($_POST['fname']=="")
    {           
        $err ="Please Enter your first name"."<br>";
        array_push($error_array,$err);      
    }
    else
    {
        $fname = test_input($_POST['fname']);       
    }

    if($_POST['lname']=="")
    {
        $err ="Please Enter your last name"."<br>";
        array_push($error_array,$err);
        $submit_Ornot_submit = true;
    }
    else
    {
        $lname = test_input($_POST["lname"]);
    }



    if($_POST['email']=="")
    {       
        $err ="Please Enter your email"."<br>";
        array_push($error_array,$err);
    }
    else
    {
        $email_Value = $_POST['email']; 
        $position_Of_at  = strpos("$email_Value","@");      
        $position_Of_dot = strpos("$email_Value",".");

        if($position_Of_at == -1 || $position_Of_dot == -1 || ($position_Of_at + 2) >= $position_Of_dot )
        {
            $err = "Please enter valid Email"."<br>";
            array_push($error_array,$err);          
        }
        else
        {
           $email = test_input($_POST["email"]);
        }
    }

    if($_POST['dob']=="")
    {
        $err ="Please Enter your date of birth"."<br>";
        array_push($error_array,$err);
    }
    else
    {
        $dob = test_input($_POST["dob"]);
    }

    if(!isset($_POST["gender"]))
    {
        $err ="Please select gender"."<br>";
        array_push($error_array,$err);
    }
    else
    {
        $gender = $_POST["gender"];
        if ($gender == "Male")
        {
            $Mchecked = "checked";
        }
        else if ($gender == "Female")
        {
            $Fchecked = "checked";
        }
    }

    if(!isset($_POST['hobbies']))
    {
        $err ="Please Enter your hobbies"."<br>";
        array_push($error_array,$err);
    }
    else
    {
        $hobbies = test_input($_POST['hobbies']);
    }
}

function test_input($data)
{
   $data = trim($data);
   $data = stripslashes($data);
   $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
   return $data;
}


?>
```

Continuing - HTML & PHP and Javascript: (this code is the same file)

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Ragistration Form</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ragistration_form.css">

<script src="jquery-2.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
/*
$(document).ready(function(event)
{    
    $(".sbt_button").click(function(event)
    {        
        var error_arr = [];             
        var email_value = $("#email").val();                    
        var position_of_at  = email_value.indexOf('@');         
        var position_of_dot = email_value.lastIndexOf('.');



        if($("#fname").val() == null || $("#fname").val() == "")
        {
             var err = "First Name";
             error_arr.push(err);
        }

        if($("#lname").val() == null || $("#lname").val() == "")
        {
            var err = "Last Name ";
            error_arr.push(err);
        }
        if(position_of_at == -1 || position_of_dot == -1 || (position_of_at + 2) >= position_of_dot )
        {
            var err = "Email ";
            error_arr.push(err);
        }

        if($("#dob").val() == null || $("#dob").val() == "")
        {
            var err = "Date of Birth ";
            error_arr.push(err);
        }

        if(!$("input[type='radio']").is(":checked"))
        {
            var err = "Gender ";
            error_arr.push(err);
        }

        if(!$("input[type='checkbox']").is(":checked"))
        {
            var err = "Hobbies ";
            error_arr.push(err);
        }


        if(error_arr.length !=0)
        {
            event.preventDefault(); 
            alert(error_arr);   
        }           
    });
});

*/
</script>

</head>
<body>
<form class="form" name="myForm" action="" method="POST">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <p class="heading">Ragistration Form</p>
    </tr>
    <?php
if($error_array !="")
{   
    foreach($error_array as $value)
    {       
        echo "<tr style='color:red;'><td> ". $value. "</td></tr>";                  
    }
}

?>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="field_Name">First Name :<b style="color:red">*</b></td>
      <td><input type="text" name="fname" id="fname" class="inputfield_Name"  /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="field_Name">Last Name :<b style="color:red">*</b></td>
      <td><input type="text" name="lname" id="lname" class="inputfield_Name"  /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="field_Name">Email :<b style="color:red">*</b></td>
      <td><input type="text" name="email" id="email" class="inputfield_Name"   /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="field_Name">Date of Birth :<b style="color:red">*</b></td>
      <td><input type="date" name="dob" id="dob"  class="inputfield_Name"   /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="field_Name">Gender :<b style="color:red">*</b></td>

        <td><input type="radio" name="gender" value="Male"class="inputfield_Name" <?php echo $Mchecked;?>   />Male
        <input type="radio" name="gender" value="Female" <?php echo $Fchecked;?>    />
        Female</td>


    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="field_Name">About Yourself :</td>
      <td><textarea name="abt" class="inputfield_Name"$></textarea></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="field_Name">Hobbies :<b style="color:red">*</b></td>
      <td><input name="hobbies" value="Cricket"  type="checkbox" id="hobbies"  class="inputfield_Name"    />
        Cricket
        <input name="hobbies" value="Singing"   type="checkbox"   />
        Singing
        <input name="hobbies" value="Travling"   type="checkbox"  />
        Travling</td>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td><input name="hobbies"  value="Writing"  type="checkbox"  class="inputfield_Name"  />
        Writing
        <input name="hobbies"  value="Teaching"  type="checkbox"   />
        Teaching
        <input name="hobbies"  value="Driving"  type="checkbox"   />
        Driving </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td><input type="submit" value="Ragister" name="sbt_save"  class="sbt_button"/></td>
        </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I think your code is OK

Comment: PHP is never going to prevent a form being submitted - it's server side.  Your jQuery code looks like it might have some hope of doing so, but it's all commented out currently via the `/*  */` tags.

Comment: Try checking` $_POST['email']==null` condition as well, also I have answered the question so you can check it, whether it works or not, @Shanky

Comment: You can use HTML5 validation just add `required` attribute to required fields;

Answer (score 1):

Your Workable **HTML+Jquery** Code and rest of the **PHP** code is OK.
**PHP** not prevent form submission.You can prevent Form submission by **HTML**(`required` field) AND using **Jquery**

```js
$(document).ready(function(event)
{    
    $(".sbt_button").click(function(event)
    {        
        var error_arr = [];             
        var email_value = $("#email").val();                    
        var position_of_at  = email_value.indexOf('@');         
        var position_of_dot = email_value.lastIndexOf('.');



        if($("#fname").val() == null || $("#fname").val() == "")
        {
             var err = "First Name";
             error_arr.push(err);
        }

        if($("#lname").val() == null || $("#lname").val() == "")
        {
            var err = "Last Name ";
            error_arr.push(err);
        }
        if(position_of_at == -1 || position_of_dot == -1 || (position_of_at + 2) >= position_of_dot )
        {
            var err = "Email ";
            error_arr.push(err);
        }

        if($("#dob").val() == null || $("#dob").val() == "")
        {
            var err = "Date of Birth ";
            error_arr.push(err);
        }

        if(!$("input[type='radio']").is(":checked"))
        {
            var err = "Gender ";
            error_arr.push(err);
        }

        if(!$("input[type='checkbox']").is(":checked"))
        {
            var err = "Hobbies ";
            error_arr.push(err);
        }


        if(error_arr.length !=0)
        {
            event.preventDefault(); 
            alert(error_arr);   
        }           
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form class="form" name="myForm" action="" method="POST">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <p class="heading">Ragistration Form</p>
    </tr>
    
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="field_Name">First Name :<b style="color:red">*</b></td>
      <td><input type="text" name="fname" id="fname" class="inputfield_Name"  /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="field_Name">Last Name :<b style="color:red">*</b></td>
      <td><input type="text" name="lname" id="lname" class="inputfield_Name"  /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="field_Name">Email :<b style="color:red">*</b></td>
      <td><input type="text" name="email" id="email" class="inputfield_Name"   /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="field_Name">Date of Birth :<b style="color:red">*</b></td>
      <td><input type="date" name="dob" id="dob"  class="inputfield_Name"   /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="field_Name">Gender :<b style="color:red">*</b></td>

        <td><input type="radio" name="gender" value="Male"class="inputfield_Name"  />Male
        <input type="radio" name="gender" value="Female"    />
        Female</td>


    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="field_Name">About Yourself :</td>
      <td><textarea name="abt" class="inputfield_Name"$></textarea></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="field_Name">Hobbies :<b style="color:red">*</b></td>
      <td><input name="hobbies" value="Cricket"  type="checkbox" id="hobbies"  class="inputfield_Name"    />
        Cricket
        <input name="hobbies" value="Singing"   type="checkbox"   />
        Singing
        <input name="hobbies" value="Travling"   type="checkbox"  />
        Travling</td>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td><input name="hobbies"  value="Writing"  type="checkbox"  class="inputfield_Name"  />
        Writing
        <input name="hobbies"  value="Teaching"  type="checkbox"   />
        Teaching
        <input name="hobbies"  value="Driving"  type="checkbox"   />
        Driving </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td><input type="submit" value="Ragister" name="sbt_save"  class="sbt_button"/></td>
        </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of jquery you can directly manage it using **PHP**.

Just try to check the NULL condition as well. Here is the code.

```
if($_POST['fname']=="" || $_POST['fname']==null)
    {           
        $err ="Please Enter your first name"."<br>";
        array_push($error_array,$err);      
    }
    else
    {
        $fname = test_input($_POST['fname']);       
    }
```

OR if you want it to be done using **HTML**, simply add `required` attribute in your input type.

Just like :

```
<input type="text" name="fname" id="fname" required>
```

Comment: @shanky, please check the answer if it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

1.Check if any textboxes are empty before checking if submit button is cliked

```
if( isset($_POST['fname']) && 
    isset($_POST['lname']) &&
    isset($_POST['email']) &&
    isset($_POST['dob']) &&
    isset($_POST["gender"]) &&
    isset($_POST['hobbies'])
  )  {  
         //your php code here 
     } else {  echo "Please complete the form"; }
```

2.Use Javascript form Validation

```
<form class="form" name="myForm" action="" method="POST"  onsubmit="return validateForm();">

<script>function validateForm() {  
    //your form validation code here 
} </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to check the form values. So do something like this.

Under

```
if(isset($_POST["sbt_save"]))
{
```

Put this code

```
if($_POST['dob']=="" || $_POST['email']=="" || $_POST['lname']=="" || $_POST['gender'] == ""]){

$err ="Please Enter all form fields"."<br>";
        array_push($error_array,$err); }else{
```

the rest of your code...

Also check out [jquery validator plugin](http://jqueryvalidation.org). Some browsers like mobile safari don't recognize required tag and will submit the form.

Answer (score 0):

To Stop submitting the form you have to use the browser side validation i.e either use jquery validation or simple javascript.

Or another way is use HTML 5 Validation i.e. required attribute in your input field.

This will stop your form to submit until your all fields are fills and validate.

After this use server side validation, check if any of the field is empty then return and highlight that particular field.

Comment: how can I retain values of textarea after submitting form in php here is my code - <td class="field_Name">About Yourself :</td>
      <td><textarea name="abt"><?php echo $abt;?></textarea></td>

Comment: <?php echo $abt; ?>  will not work you have to use your method to get the value i.e. either post or get.

Comment: here you will retain value by printing $_POST['abt']

Comment: also have check like <?php if(isset($_POST['abt'])) { echo $_POST['abt'];}